# java error heap space memory in latest android studio?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I am getting the java heap space error from last five days and gradle build is failed. I have tried everything but unfortunately I am unable to fix this issue. Any who can help me. Thanks in Advance.

[this is the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzrvc.png)

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help if you could post the error message as text, the error message is not fully displayed.  More info on how you are building, the build file would help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems that the problem is with your JVM `-Xms` and `-Xmx` arguments, you should be able to edit them in the gradle `gradle.propertie`. For example if I want to set my min heap size to 1GB and a max of 2GB I'd do something like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

The other value that you might want to tweak is the IDE's heap min/max, can be found in the help tab **Help > Edit Custom VM Options** should prompt you with a file to edit those arguments.

> FYI: The default values for Xmx is based on the physical memory of the machine. 25% if physical memory is above 2G, and 50% if below for Java 11, and 50% of physical memory for Java 8. Which means probably you are doing too much work on your PC (running an overpowered Emulator I assume :)

Comment: SaleemKhair! Thanks for your response. I have tried this but did not work me?